# the error says it gives boolean value

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I get an **error** on the `$count` part for validating if data exists, 
it says that

> it returns boolean values

but I don't get why. I've put a comment on which line, where the error is located.

```
    $check = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `request` WHERE `Request_ID`=''"));
    $count = mysql_num_rows($check); // error is here 

    if($count > 0){
        ?>
        <script>
            alert('Data Already Exist!');
        </script>
        <?php

    }else{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `request` (`Request_Name`, `Request_Date`, `Request_By`,`Description`,`Quantity`, `Price`, `Destination`,`Reason`) VALUES ('$name', '$date', '$req','$desc','$qty','$prc','$dest','$reason',)");
    ?>
    <script>
        window.location = "home.php#requi.php";
    </script>
    <?php
    }
```

}

How to fix this?

Comment: Can you share your updated code ? If still not worked ?

Comment: Hi Leah, you need to provide some value for Request_ID in your query  $check = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `request` WHERE `Request_ID`='someid'"));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only call `mysql_num_rows` on a result obejct.
If you want to get the num rows of the result you have to use this code:

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `request` WHERE `Request_ID`=''");
$count = mysql_num_rows($check); // error should be gone

//Optional:
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($check, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
    $result[] = $data;//To get all rows, one by one
}
```

On another note I would nto recomment to use mysql, use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/de/book.mysqli.php) instead, if you need help with this I will gladly assist you further.

Comment: can you give us the output of `var_dump($check, $count)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `mysql_num_rows()` to replace `mysql_fetch_array()`.

Check reference [**here**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

Answer (score 0):

mysql_fetch_array:

```
Returns an array of strings that corresponds to the fetched row, or FALSE if there are no more rows.
```

My guess is that it return false. Which is why you get the error.